# Cannot create project with different name than location - 'overlaps with another project'

Tags: eclipse

[<image for reference>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dlx6i.png)

Whatever I type instead of "TestProjectLocation", it always says 'the name overlaps with another existing project' (which does not exist and never has). Is the issue that I'm trying to put the project in my active workspace, just under a different name? If so, how can I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse may be having some trouble with the location of your workspace.

Try using another empty workspace(In a different folder or at least in a higher hierarchy.

Comment: Actually Eclipse does allow projects with the 'location' in a subfolder. In fact that is the recommended layout for Eclipse RCP development.

Comment: Is that so? I stand corrected then, thanks for the clarification.